# Compile Protobuff generated C# file into dll

Tags: c#, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I am trying to compile proto file to dll so can read IMessage.

CS file gets generated from .proto file. However when I try to do
Assemby.GetCurrentAssembly etc to get IMessage I dont get anything.

Please suggest.

Edit:
Basically a user will add a proto file as input and application will be able to parse the proto file and create a custom json.

Comment: This makes little sense to me. You have generated a c# class for your protobuf model. You would typically then use the generated type to deserialize your message. What does `GetCurrentAssembly` have to do with anything?  If you want a .dll, why not just compile the .cs file into one? What is it you are trying to do?

Comment: i want to generate a dll at runtime and use it to parse imessage. a user will add a proto file as input and application will parse the proto file and create a custom json. clear?